# "Flattening" a List in Scala & Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell

Given a `List[Option[Int]]`:

```
scala> list
res8: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None)
```

I can get `List(1,2)`, i.e. extract the `list` via `flatMap` and `flatten`:

```
scala> list.flatten
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> list.flatMap(x => x)
res10: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Given the following `[Maybe Int]` in Haskell, how can I perform the above operation?

I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
import Control.Monad

maybeToList :: Maybe a -> [b]
maybeToList Just x  = [x]
maybeToList Nothing = []

flatten' :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
flatten' xs = xs >>= (\y -> y >>= maybeToList)
```

Comment: `(\y -> y >>= maybeToList)` reduces to `(>>= maybeToList)`, right?

Comment: Your `flatten'` won't type because `y` is in a different `Monad` than the result of `maybeToList`.  To fix it you can change `y` into `return y`, but `return y >>= maybeToList` is equivalent to `maybeToList y` by the monad laws, and so you end up with @Lee's version.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen - could you please explain why `return` is required? Isn't the type of `y` in `... (\y -> y >>= maybeToList)` `Maybe a`?

Comment: Yes, `y` is `Maybe a`. But that means that a function `f` used with `y >>= f` must have type `a -> Maybe b`, which does not fit the type of `maybeToList`.  You want to pass `y` itself to `maybeToList`, not its `a` content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `catMaybes`:

```
import Data.Maybe
catMaybes xs
```

if you want to use `>>=` you need a function `Maybe a -> [a]`. This is `maybeToList`:

```
xs >>= maybeToList
```

As the comment point out, you can convert any `Foldable` to a list so you can make `flatten'` more general:

```
flatten' :: Foldable f => [f a] -> [a]
flatten' xs = xs >>= toList
```

Comment: If you want an answer somewhat more general than just for `Maybe`, you can use `Data.Foldable.toList` instead of `maybeToList`.

Answer (score 9):

You could have just asked [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[Maybe%20a]%20-%3E%20[a]). It's a search engine for Haskell functions: you enter a type and it proposes functions that can be used at such type.  For the type `[Maybe a] -> [a]`, its first result is `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe`.

Comment: Ack, I've added some more explanation as you suggest.